# Get data from database using date groups in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am using laravel and I am trying to get data from database grouped by the column "created_at".
The data into created_at column is being stored is in the below format,

```
2020-07-23 07:03:59
```

My question is , how can we fetch the data using group for dates only.
For example , All the records should be grouped into one array/object with same dates.

I tried executing the following query,

```
 $transactions= MyTransaction::where('id','=',$user->id)->orderBy('created_at')->get()->groupBy(function($item) {
                return $item->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
            });
```

but it does not return what i am expecting, it considers the seconds and hours into the consideration too.

Please guide me solving this query.

Comment: You can't group results in an array with mysql/eloquent, groupBy is used to condese all results into 1 row per group, this is mainly used for `count()` like functions. Your best option is to either sort the options after query with php. Or do a seperate query for each group.

Comment: @Merijndk : Thanks for the quick reply. Can you please guide me more to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

```php
  $column = \DB::raw("CONCAT(YEAR(`ride_date`),'-',MONTH(`ride_date`),'-',DAY(`ride_date`)) AS `group_column`");


 $transactions= MyTransaction::select('*',$column)->where('id','=',$user->id)->orderBy('created_at')->groupBy('group_column')->get();
```